# Laravel Ajax document ready function issue

Tags: ajax, laravel

i have two function in my laravel in my code, which i want to call, i searched on internet but i could not solve the issue, please check;

**Ajax Code:**

```
<script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
    var $datasearch=$('#datasearch');
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(teachers){
            $datasearch.empty();
            for (var i=0; i<teachers.length; i++){

                $datasearch.append('<tr>'
                +'<td>'+teachers[i].efirst+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" value="1">edit</button>'+'</td>'
                +'</tr>');
            }
        });
    });
});    });
    </script>
```

**Update.Js** function which i want to call from ajax code, when edit button is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function($)  {
var a= $('#update-id').attr("value")

        $('.edit-btn').on('click',function (e){

    $('#update-form').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "teachers/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                        let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
               teacher.forEach(item => { $(`[name=${item[0]}]`).val(item[1]); });
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: what you want
?

Comment: @vivek_23 update.js function is not being called from ajax code, when i click on edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function($)  {
var a= $('#update-id').attr("value")


$('body').on('click','.edit-btn',function(){
alert(1);

    $('#update-form').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "teachers/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                        let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
               teacher.forEach(item => { $(`[name=${item[0]}]`).val(item[1]); });
                },
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: update.js function is not being called from ajax code, when i click on edit

Answer (score 0):

check the source tab in your dev debugger browser (F12 on chrome)
is the file already loaded?

and then, try to remove $ in param like this :

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
   var a= $('#update-id').attr("value")

    $('.edit-btn').on('click',function (e){

    $('#update-form').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "teachers/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    let teacher = Object.entries(data.teacher);
           teacher.forEach(item => { $(`[name=${item[0]}]`).val(item[1]); });
            },
        });
    });
});
```